# mongoose do not display unnecessary lines from the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to output sorted list from database.

I do so

```
const subs = await Sub.find({}, {userName: 1, score: 1, _id: 0}).sort({ score: 'desc' });
```

And in the end I get this list like this

> { userName: 'test1', score: 14 },{ userName: 'test2', score: 2 },{ userName: 'test3', score: 1 },{ userName: 'test4', score: 0 }

How can I remove unnecessary lines here so that something like this comes out in the response

> 'test1' score: 14, 'test2' score: 2, 'test3' score: 1, 'test4' score: 0

I work with tmi.js

```
async function leaderboardHandler(chan, userstate) {
  const subs = await Sub.aggregate([
    {$sort: {score: -1}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, res: [{k: "$userName", v: "$score"}]}},
    {$set: {res: {$arrayToObject: ["$res"]}}},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
  ])

  client.say(chan, `@${userstate.username} leaderboard: ${subs}`);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to remove? "username"?. Why would you want to do so. You can get the response with username and socre and display to the user the way you want in the client side.

Comment: Do you want to return a single long string?

Comment: @nimrodserok i want to return only values, no names

Comment: @nacho I don’t get it, I get this array, but I can’t do anything with it

Comment: But what is the data type? The current result is an array of objects, what is the requested data type?

Comment: @nimrodserok for the username, string is obtained

Comment: `'test1' score: 14, 'test2' score: 2, 'test3' score: 1, 'test4' score: 0` This thing is not an array, not an object and not a string. What is this?

Comment: @nimrodserok This is approximately what I would like to receive, the values ​​​​from the array that I receive from the database

Comment: You should define what you want, one option is: `{'test1': 14, 'test2':2...}`. This is an object...

Comment: @nimrodserok yes, that would be the option that suits me

Comment: Another option will be: `[{'test1': 14}, {'test2':2},...]` - If order is important. This is an array of objects

Comment: @nimrodserok It is important that the sorting remains, otherwise everything suits me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using an aggregation pipeline with `$arrayToObject`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {score: -1}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, res: [{k: "$userName", v: "$score"}]}},
  {$set: {res: {$arrayToObject: ["$res"]}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-_Wb2b44H8a)

Comment: I tried to do `const subs = await Sub.aggregate([
    {$sort: {score: -1}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, res: [{k: "$userName", v: "$score"}]}},
    {$set: {res: {$arrayToObject: ["$res"]}}},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
  ])`

Comment: But I end up with this `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: Added full code to the topic

Comment: This is only the way you print...

Comment: Try console.log(JSON.stringify(subs ))

Comment: everything is working now, thanks a lot